# How To Make Text A Hyperlink?

Tags: css, html

Here, I am trying to make `<p>Lex</p>` a hyperlink without using `<a>` tag and using css, so that on right click of above `<p>Lex</p>` `Open Link In New Tab` can be accessed.
Below is Html and CSS

```
<style>
p{
    color:red;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>

<p>LexL Luther</p>
```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid an `<a>` tag? Can you please clarify.

Comment: CSS can not help you here.

Comment: If you just want to make sure, that the link is opened in a new tab, you can use `target_blank`: `<a href="https//..." target="_blank">Lex</a>`

Comment: What exactly would you expect to happen when you open "Lex" in a new tab? It isn't a URL.

Comment: anchor tags are meant for this, should be able to do this in in-line HTML but . . . not typical

Comment: Quite simply, **without javascript** THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a tag to make a hyperlink.

You can use _blank to open link in a new tab.

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

The target="_blank" does this in the code above.

Comment: OP explicitly says _"without using `<a>` tag"_

Comment: If possible, let me know.

Comment: It isn't possible. But your answer is the complete opposite of OPs requirement.